# Virtual Environment for each project in Pycharm

Tags: pycharm, virtualenv

I want to use a separate virtual environment for each project in Pycharm. For this purpose, I created a virtual environment for each project. I can not find a clear documentation **if I need to activate/deactivate these virtual environments for each project when I want to add or remove things through PIP command or its done automatically in Pycharm terminal for that specific open project.** I think it might be later case because when I use `pip -V` then I get a different virtual environment for each project.

Would be nice to hear from someone who has used virtual environment in Pycharm to see if I am on the right track.

I followed this method to create the virtual environment.

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/creating-virtual-environment.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you are on the right track. However, the things which are happening are pretty explicit, not "automatically" and behind the scenes. In `Settings | Project | Project Interpreter` you select the interpreter (or virtual interpreter) you want to use/add packages/remove packages. When you create a virtual env you can select to share it between projects. For you, don't do this. If you did, just make sure all of your projects are pointing to different (virtual) interpreters and not the same one.

Comment: @nanoteck thanks. The project interpreter is automatically set to virtual environment when I create the virtual environment. I was more confused about where to install the new packages when I do pip. Do I have to activate the virtual environment for it or not? If I run a pip command in the  terminal of open project window, should be sufficient?

Comment: Personally I've never used `pip` inside of `PyCharm`. [This](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/installing-uninstalling-and-upgrading-packages.html) is the preferred method. If you want to install new packages, go to `Settings | Project | Project Interpreter`.  Clicking on a package and hitting `-` is the preferred method for removing. For you, click on the `+` symbol. You will then have a window which is the interface for installing packages. Basically just click on the package you want and hit install.

Comment: Doing pip in the Pycharm terminal is the same as what you mentioned here I tested it. Installed packages through that terminal are not visible in other virtual environments so it means that I do not need to manually activate/deactivate the virtual environment.